# COMO PUEDO PROCESAR LOS DATOS PARA LA AUTENTICACION DE UN LOGIN?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Tengo un formulario de login echo en **html** con sus estilos **CSS**.
Para las rutas cree un **blueprint** llamado **auth**, donde desarrollo en siguiente codigo

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for, session
from . import auth
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from pymysql.cursors import DictCursor

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = '5L1NA'

mysql = MySQL(cursorclass=DictCursor)
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'haruko.17'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'residenciadb'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)


@auth.route('/login', methods=["GET","POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        nombre_usuario = request.form['nombre_usuario']
        clave = request.form['clave']
        
        conn = mysql.connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombre_usuario=%s', (nombre_usuario))
        user = cursor.fetchone()
        cursor.close()
        
        if len(user)>0:
            if clave == user['clave']:
                session['nombre_usuario'] = user['nombre_usuario']
                session['clave'] = user['clave']
                
                return url_for('auth.menu')
            else:
                return 'error'
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')
```

Pero de esta forma al llenar el formulario y darle click en iniciar
me muestra el siguiente error

*the session is unavailable because no secret key was set. set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.*

Comment: Estás definiendo tu secret key en `app` pero veo que estás usando `auth` para las rutas. Solo deberías definir una sola app usando `Flask()`. ¿Qu{e hay en tu módulo auth?

Comment: @César en mi carpeta auth tengo dos archivos, el __init__.py. Y el archivo views.py qe contiene la ruta /login